# How to pull up a keyboard - iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I've dealt with Keyboards with a UITextField but how can I use a Keyboard in the following way:

- I have a UITableView
- When the user selects a specific row, a keyboard pops up
- I'd like to have a method that knows everytime a letter or something is pressed on the keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place text fields on the cells using the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and give the text field on each cell its own tag to identify it in the table view or text field delegate methods. Optionally, have a cell's text field become first responder when the cell is tapped in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` (outside of the text field's region).

To make it look like part of the cells, ensure your text fields don't have borders and match the cell background color.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a tiny (1x1) invisible/transparent text field in the corner somewhere (temporarily make it a subview in the table view cell or on top of the entire table view), make the text field first responder, and trap any character inputs by implementing the text should change delegate and inspecting the replacement text before it's entered.

Answer (score 0):

const CGRect kbottomPickerViewFrame = {{0.0f, 480.0f},{320.0f, 298.0f}};
const CGRect ktopPickerViewFrame = {{0.0f, 480-298},{320.0,298.0f}};

-(void) animateViewUp:(BOOL)up {

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    if(up) {

        self.view.frame = ktopPickerViewFrame;

    }else {

        self.view.frame = kbottomPickerViewFrame;

    }

} completion:nil];
```

}

use this method it will animate the view . Call it when textField begin editing